# kotlin loop over 2 lists of different lengths

Tags: kotlin

hopefully you can give me some advice about a problem that I've solved but I'm not happy with.

I have this code

```
val allTeams = (0 until teamNumber)
        .map { Team() }

var idx = 0
playerNames.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
     .map {
         it.trim()
         it.capitalize(Locale.ROOT)
     }
     .shuffled()
     .forEach {
         allTeams[idx].addPlayer(it)
         if(idx == allTeams.size - 1) idx = 0 else idx++
     }
```

If i give this code teamNumber 3 and the playerNames ['a','b','c','d','e'] for example it creates 3 teams and then it loops over the playernames and puts them in a team, if it reaches the max length of allTeams it changes the var idx to 0 and keeps going.

My question is, is there a way to do this without maintaining that ugly index var?

This was my other solution using recursion but its not very nice either.

```
tailrec fun addToTeam(  names: List<String>, teamIdx: Int = 0, nameIdx: Int = 0){
        if (nameIdx == names.size) return
        allTeams[teamIdx].addPlayer(names[nameIdx])
        if (teamIdx == allTeams.size - 1) addToTeam(names,0, nameIdx+1 )
        else addToTeam(names,teamIdx+1, nameIdx+1 )
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for `zip`.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html

Comment: I checked out zip but it seems to stop when it reaches the end of either list?

Comment: You are throwing away the result of your `it.trim()` call. You should chain the `captilize` call onto it. e.g. `it.trim().capitalize(Locale.ROOT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting problem!

Yes, your code is a bit ugly, but I can't spot a solution which is much neater.

First, a couple of minor tweaks: the name `idx` is pretty meaningless and likely to be confusing; perhaps something like `teamIdx` would be clearer.  Conversely, `allTeams` could probably be just `teams`.  And a more common way of updating it would be:

```
teamIdx = (teamIdx + 1) % teams.size
```

However, that's not helping very much.

One approach might be to split the names into chunks, and then zip each chunk with the teams:

```
playerNames
    // filter &c here
    .chunked(teams.size)
    .forEach {
        it.zip(teams).forEach { (player, team) ->
            team += player
        }
    }
```

This is also ugly, as it has not one but *two* nested `forEach()` calls (which are a bit of a code smell).  But it avoids an explicit index.

Like your code, this approach copes properly if the number of players isn't an exact multiple of the number of teams.  If you know it always is, then there's probably a slightly better way using `addAll()` instead of the second `forEach()`.

If I were writing this, I'd probably split out a utility function to make it clearer.  Maybe a function similar to `zip()` but repeating the second list until the end of the first.  Or a function to split a list evenly into nearly-equal-sized groups, like `chunked()` but letting the chunk sizes vary by 1 instead of letting the last chunk be much smaller.

Comment: You can omit the inner "`.forEach`" and destructuring: `it.zip(teams) { player, team -> team += player }`. It will produce a throw-away list of Units, but the above produces an intermediate list of pairs so it's no more wasteful.

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion toegether with Tenfours04's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to present another approach, where creation of teams is combined with adding players to them:

```kotlin
val players = playerNames.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    .map { it.trim().capitalize(Locale.ROOT) }
    .shuffled()

val allTeams = if (players.size < teamNumber) {
    List(teamNumber) { index ->
        Team().also { if (index < players.size) it.addPlayer(players[index]) }
    }
} else {
    val lastChunkSize = players.size % teamNumber
    val lastChunk = players.takeLast(lastChunkSize)
    players
        .dropLast(lastChunkSize)
        .chunked(playerNames.size / teamNumber)
        .mapIndexed { index, chunk ->
            Team(chunk).also { if (index < lastChunkSize) it.addPlayer(lastChunk[index]) }
        }
}
```

Note, that this code assumes there is a constructor in `Team` class accepting list of players.